# xsl xml populate tables next to each other

Tags: xml, xslt

I wished to create tables with multiple rows and two columns.
Now, once i create these tables i want them to be placed next to each other and not below each other so that i can use the horizontal space.

tblformat: needed

```
id  | 1 |   id  | 2    |
name|abc|   name| abc2 |
addr|xyz|   addr|xyz2  |
```

instead of

```
      id | 1 |
     name|abc|
     addr|xyz|
      id | 2 |
     name|abc2|
     addr|xyz2|
```

So far i have written a long code with xslt and I donot wish to paste it here. I just need the logic to achieve this. xml fragment is like this:

```
<nodes>
 <node>
  <id> 1 </id>
  <name> abc </name>
  <addr> xyz </addr>
 </node>
 <node>
  <id> 2 </id>
  <name> abc2 </name>
  <addr> xyz2 </addr>
 </node>
</nodes>
```

Comment: Is this HTML output?  Can you edit the question to include samples of the current HTML you are producing (i.e. the actual HTML tags, not an ASCII-art rendering of how it appears in a browser) and how you want it to be.  Do you want two separate tables side by side (which could be as simple as adding `style="float:left;` in the appropriate place) or one table with four columns?

Comment: put it in one table with an empty column if needed, or put each table into a table cell of another two column table.